# How to correctly improve gitflow branching model?

Tags: git, git-workflow

Нi. I'm fairly new to Git, but we're going to use it in our project and looking for convenient workflow. The Gitflow is rather good for us (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), but with some modifications. The problem is that at the release time not all of the features in develop passed tests and can't be included to release branch. So we can't start release branch from develop.
If I understand this correctly, I should start all the feature branches and release branch from the last release tag. Merge feature branches into develop. But no back-merge into the feature. And when feature are ready for release, I should merge it straight to release branch. So I have to do a lot of merges (each task of current sprint ready for release must be merged) instead of one merge with develop in classic gitflow. It can be 10s of branches per sprint. It's looks like not really good. So does any way to do less hand work in that case? Or maybe I have wrong in this situation and there is other suitable workflow for my case? Thanks in advance! And sorry for my English :)

Comment: I don't understand your scenario; surely the solution is simply not to merge broken features back into develop.

Comment: "I should start all the feature branches and release branch from the last release tag" - this is not a good model...

Comment: Feature is not really broken. We have an issue and when it finished it merged to develop for QA department tests. They use test server with develop branch on it. But some issues have low priority and sometimes not tested for release time. So we can't include it for release.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth "this is not a good model" - I have to do that because of this situation, that in develop can be commits that will not be included to release. So I can’t start my issue from develop. Otherwise it will be hard to include my issue to release if my branch has those commits.

Comment: @AnnaOdegova why "in develop can be commits that will not be included to release"? I would say that everything you're pushing to develop we'll be included in the next release, so just don't push to develop what you don't expect in your next release. You can use other branches to test the feature's integration if you want.